# Is this NSTimer dealloc acceptable or will it produce an unexpected error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I was duplicating my code, so I refactored it like this:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [self resetTimer];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) resetTimer {
    if( timer != nil ) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    timer = nil;
    // set some other value to zero...
}
```

Is it acceptable to call this resetTimer method in the dealloc method?  Otherwise I will end up writing the same 4 lines in resetTimer twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did same thing, and it worked fine for me.  (Although I do rely on the nil call, so it's just:)

```
-(void) resetTimer {
   [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: I add the check in case it's invalidated elsewhere.  It shouldn't be, but I'm playing it safe.

Comment: @Javoid: Messages to nil are valid in Objective-C. If `timer` is nil, then sending it `invalidate` just won't do anything. Checking if an object is nil before sending it a message is always pointless.

Comment: If the timer was invalidated, but not set to nil, then sending it a message will cause a crash.

Comment: @Javoid: Comparing the timer to nil (which is the if-statement we're talking about here) will not guard against that condition. The only protection against dangling pointers is to avoid creating them.

Answer (score 4):

What @mackworth said:

```
-(void) resetTimer {
   [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

However, you didn't show the timer's creation.  If it is something like:

```
timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 42 target:self ...] retain];
```

Then your object's `dealloc` will never be invoked anyway.  At least, not without an over-release bug in your code.

A timer retains its target.  Thus, a timer created as above will create a retain cycle between your object and the timer.

One solution is to explicitly call `resetTimer` when you want the timer to stop (I'd call it `invalidateTimer` as reset implies that you are resetting the timer to continue running).

Another is to *not* retain the timer and *not* release it in `dealloc`.   Looks a bit wonky, but sometimes you have to play these kinds of weak reference games.

Comment: I don't retain timers, never saw the need.  As long as it's firing or waiting to fire, it retains it's own reference.  Good point with method naming.

Comment: the solution you suggest will keep the timer runing even after it's delegate has been released and if it's not a view, let's sat NSObject you don't know when it will be released so you can't invalidate before that. BOTTOM LINE: does anyone have a proper example for setting and stoping timers (if you log the timer callback you will still see it runing...)

Comment: No it won't;  once the timer is invalidated, it'll never fire again and is rescheduled from the run loop.